# .NET HttpClient does not timed out for in non console app

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I need to run an ASP.NET WebAPI (.NET Framework 4.6.1) application in a network which is behind a firewall and I need to call some APIs which are hosted out of that network. I can hit those API with Postman from the same machine without any issue, but the HTTP client GetAsync method times out and fails.

I have created multiple applications using Visual Studio templates and put the following code in them (basically nothing expect the template code and following lines):

```
 var c = new HttpClient();
 var r = await c.GetAsync("https://google.com");
```

Above code works fine with .NET Framework 4.6.1 Console Application but fails on all other application types including:

- ASP.NET Web Application .NET Framework 4.6.1
- ASP.NET Core Web Application 2.2
- .NET Core Console Application 2.2

I've also tried to bypass SSL cert using below code without any luck.

`httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };`

For sure something on the network causing this, but what, hand how does this work in a .NET Framework and not any other one? 
I've tired public sites like google.com and I got the same result. 
Has anyone run to the same issue? any suggestion on how to debug it?

Comment: What is the exact error you receieve? Does it always happens after a set amount of time or does it vary? Would it make sense to increase the timeout? How much data are you expecting to receieve back? How long does Postman take to run those requests?

Comment: My wild guess is that you are running your console app as yourself but running the web app as a service account identity of some kind, and that identity lacks a certain aspect of your configuration, e.g. it doesn't have permissions to access an outbound proxy server or a root certificate needed for the connection. But that is just a guess. There's not much information to go on here.

Comment: The response from postman is just a few milliseconds. I'm literally trying  google.com and the connection is very fast.

Comment: @JohnWu I'm not hosting this app yet. the .net core is also a console app but it fails.

Comment: @mason Error message is: "a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or the established connection failed because the host has failed to respond"

Comment: @FredJand: Are you blocking on a task (e.g., `Wait` or `Result`) further up your call stack?

Comment: @StephenCleary For the web application, It is in an action method of a controller something like public async Task<string> Get { .[the above code].. }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find the solution for .NET Framework Web Application. By adding below to the web.config, the default proxy would be set.

```
<system.net>
   <defaultproxy/>
<system.net>
```

Reference:
[Configure the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) proxy server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings)

But I do not have a working solution for .NET Core application yet.

Update 4/9/2020
I could fix the issue in .NET Core 2.x but setting config but this issue is fixed in .NET Core 3.x. Now HttpClient uses the default proxy by default.